# Updating dynamically the content property of a label with the WPF user model

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

A simple WPF window with a label on it:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:A="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="384" Width="669.114" Icon="alarmclock.ico" Closing="OnClosing" Loaded="OnLoaded" >
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
        <Label x:Name="Label1" Content="{Binding AlarmStatus}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,314,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Wire up an object so that the object can be bound to the labels content property. Yes I see the text Off on the window:

```
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        //Raise the PropertyChanged event on the UI Thread, with the relevant propertyName parameter:
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }));
    }
}

public class UserViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _alarmStatus = "Off";

    public string AlarmStatus
    {
        get { return _alarmStatus; }
        set
        {
            _alarmStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AlarmStatus"); //This is important!!!
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

I thought I would be able to change the value of the label like this:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Im setting a value but the UI does not change. The label still says Off
    UserViewModel aaaa = new UserViewModel();
    aaaa.AlarmStatus = "On";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of the ViewModel, but the View has no "connection" to that.

the `aaaa` instance dies (goes out of scope and is de-referenced) immediately after the `OnLoaded()` method finishes executing, and is garbage collected a moment later.

What you need is to grab the actual instance of the ViewModel that's currently being used by the Window:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as UserViewModel;
    viewModel.AlarmStatus = "On";
}
```

I suggest you read [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel)'s [Article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) to better understand the concept of `DataContext` in WPF.